# Sentence construction/comma usage

Tags: american-english, word-usage, british-english

So, as a rule of thumb if you remove a word or clause which has been enclosed with bracketing commas then it shouldn't destroy the meaning of the sentence.

Does this idea/rule apply to all aspects of sentence construction and comma usage or other punctuation; the notion that any isolated information in a sentence must not leave anything ungrammatical should it be removed ?  Any exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that removing nonessential information, which exists between a pair of commas (as here), should have no significant impact on the sentence:

> It's true that removing nonessential information should have no significant impact on the sentence.

However, it's not true that simply *having* two commas in a sentence means that the information between those commas is nonessential:

> I like mangoes, cherries, and kumquats.

Here, although located between two commas, *cherries* is not nonessential information. You have to analyze the sentence and determine what functional role the commas play.

---

If something really is nonessential, then removing it shouldn't impact the surrounding text. If things are constructed in such a way that it would, then either it's not *actually* nonessential or the sentence has been poorly constructed.

This also applies to other punctuation marks, such as parentheses and em dashes. However, there may be some stylistic issues:

> What I want to say, and I'm sure you'll agree—in principle—is that sentences should be formatted so that the removal of nonessential information doesn't harm anything.

The problem with this is that I have a single comma and two em dashes. Technically, I should insert a second comma after the second em dash:

> What I want to say, and I'm sure you'll agree—in principle—, is that . . .

But although there are now appropriately nested pairs of punctuation marks, this particular use is too awkward.

One solution is to replace the em dashes with parentheses, thereby allowing a second comma without difficulty:

> What I want to say, and I'm sure you'll agree (in principle), is that . . .

---

I might be proven wrong by comments or other answers, but I can't think of a situation where a sentence should be constructed in such a way that nonessential information (and its punctuation marks) couldn't be removed without doing harm to the remaining text.

Comment: An alcoholic, Reed's issues with drink were well publicised, from appearances on chat shows to a high-profile friendship with drinking partner, The Who drummer Keith Moon, with the two meeting while working on Tommy.

Comment: with drinking partner/ with the two   (This doesn't work when the non-essential information is taken out. Is there a mistake in this sentence ?

Comment: @bluebell1 The sentence is still grammatical and meaningful without the presence of *The Who drummer Keith Moon*. It doesn't convey as much information (only that his drinking partner was somebody from *Tommy*), but it still functions as a sentence. It's like giving Keith Moon's age and phone number—that would be additionally interesting, but also not necessary.